# Update: I dont know why the time difference when less than 180 seconds still adds 10 in the user rating column

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a user registration and login system that initially sets first date and time registered. Each time a user logs in i have a query that checks the time difference between the registered datetime and the current time now. if the difference in time is greater than or equal to 180seconds add 10 to the rating column of that user and reset current time of login as the new datetime/registered datetime, then redirect the user to index page.

If the time difference is less than 180 seconds just redirect the user to index page without adding a number to the rating table.

I have tried many codes did research on how to get this working all i see is cron job. i dont want to do this with cron job.

there has to be a way, please help. you guys need to save me.
This is what i have done

```
<?php
// This is part of the code

          //$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
             $_SESSION['email'] = $email;   

                date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");
                // getting the time query difference
                $sql1 = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date, NOW()) AS tdif FROM 
                          users WHERE email='$email'";  
                $result = $con->prepare($sql1);
                $result->execute();
                $result->bind_result($tdif);
                $result->fetch();

                //var_dump($tdif);

                if ($tdif >= 180) {  
          //following code suppose run once every 180seconds

        //update user's page rank
        $sql2 = "UPDATE users SET rating = rating + 10 WHERE email='$email'"; 
         $result2 = $con->query($sql2) or die("Unable to select and run query");

       //update last execution time
       $sql3 = "UPDATE users SET date = NOW() WHERE email='$email'";
       $result3 = $con->query($sql3) or die("Unable to select and run query");

         }


                    //login me in   
              redirectToIndexPage();

// This Outputs Unable to select and run query

?>
```

This code just add 10 to the rating irrespective of the time difference all the time.
in other words it keeps adding 10 each time the user logs in which is suppose to happen only after 3mins(180seconds) from last login or registered datetime

Please help i know am getting something wrong.

Comment: `var_dump($tdif);` to see what the value is.  I'm pretty sure it's going to be an array, not a single value.

Comment: Let me check it out and see.. am not sure thats going to help

Comment: You also don't need the `else` part after the time test. Just put the redirect after the closing of that `if` since you're going to redirect regardless.

Comment: ok removing the else

Comment: I tried all your suggestions, but am still getting same results.

Comment: So you've noticed that the code you have above assigns an _array_ to `$tdif`, and that your logic of comparing an array to an int isn't going to do what you think, you've updated your code to pull the desired single value from the array, compared that single value to 180, and it still doesn't work?  If that's the case, please update the code in your question to reflect what you're currently using.

Comment: Please be aware that you are using a [cargo cult prepared statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement) and you should be never doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments above you are not getting back a single value from your query as expected. The modified code below will do the same query and set your `$tdif` variable to a single value that will work in your `if` statement.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date, NOW()) AS tdif FROM users WHERE email=?";
$result = $con->prepare($sql1);
$resylt->bind_param("s",$email);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($tdif);
$result->fetch();

if ($tdif >= 180) {
     //update user's page rank
    $sql2 = "UPDATE users SET rating = rating + 10 WHERE email='$email'";
    $result2 = $con->query($sql2) or die("Unable to select and run query");
   //update last execution time
    $sql3 = "UPDATE users SET date = NOW() WHERE email='$email'";
    $result3 = $con->query($sql3) or die("Unable to select and run query");
}
redirectToIndexPage();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but now it has stopped adding value to the rating wether less than or greater than the 180 seconds

Comment: Right after `$result->fetch();` do a `var_dump($tdif);` to see what the value is you are getting.

Comment: I got int(-711)

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in your select then if you are getting a negative number. How is the `date` column defined in your table?

Comment: @Henry reverse the order of the dates in your call to `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

Comment: I did another var_dump($tdif); using the initial code i posted and i got an array of array(1) { ["tdif"]=> string(3) "-60" }

Comment: for the date column type is TIMESTAMP, default is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @PatrickQ i reversed the order of dates in the call got a this array(1) { ["tdif"]=> string(3) "151" }

Comment: If you use my code with the order reversed you should get an integer of 151. It won't trigger your `if` statement but when the difference gets big enough it will of course.

Comment: @Dave it gave me an int(151) when i var_dump($tdif); but when i tried to login and see what happens , it echoed out "Unable to select and run query"

Comment: Thanks i finally got it to work from you guys suggestions. There was a missing $result->store_result(); right after the $result->execute() which always returned unable to select and run query, and when i debugged it returned "Commands out of sycn; can not run command now" which gave me the clue where the problem actually was. I have edited your code @Dave. Thanks once again you guys saved my life